# How to fix the memory leaks in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory

I have singleton class where i have a shared instance which i am calling in multiple classes.

MenuHandler.h 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMenu *menu;

MenuHandler.m

```
+ (instancetype)defaultHandler
{
    __strong static id sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MenuHandler alloc] init]; //here it is pointing 
        NSLog(@"Menu Loaded");
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Appdelegate.m

in some Function

`[[MenuHandler defaultHandler].menu setDelegate:self];` // Here leak is pointing

samething happening for other singleton classes in my project

Any suggestions??

here are the images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cgfc.png)  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddYvY.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdpJm.png)

here what is showing in intruments [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYqeh.png) [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJzJb.png)  [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq4nK.png) [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv9co.png)

Comment: I see no actual leak here – what makes you think there would be a leak?

Comment: Objective C uses ARC which is similar to shared_ptr. Your pointer is automatically released.

Comment: i added images  in question

Comment: did you check the leaks in instruments? It will shows the line where you are getting the leaks. 95% you will get leak line. Sometimes it won't shows the exact line.

Comment: Is the `delegate` on the `menu` property `weak`?

Comment: hey i updated images which i checked with instruments.